# Update SORT_KEY_PRIMARY but got errors in android

Tags: android

This question has worried me for long time. I attempt to update contact display_name and it's working.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " +
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", 
            new String[{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}); 
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
ops.add(builder.build());
try {
    cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (RemoteException | OperationApplicationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I want to update SORT_KEY_PRIMARY, nothing happedned.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " +
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", 
            new String[{String.valueOf(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}); 
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY, sort_key);
ops.add(builder.build());
try {
    cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (RemoteException | OperationApplicationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I got error when I update display_name and sort_key_primary at meanwhile.

```
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY, pinyin);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
```

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: sort_key (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE data SET sort_key=?,data11=?,data1=?,data2=?,data10=? WHERE _id =?

Comment: you seem to be changing all names in all raw-contacts, is that really what you want? When you join contact A with contact B, and then split them they both should keep their original names.